# Spotify Web SDK Error "EMEError: No supported keysystems was found"

Tags: reactjs, electron, spotify

I literally copied and pasted the [Spotify example code](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/quick-start/#installing-the-sdk) and pasted this in my `/public/index.html` file of my React + Electron project

```
...
   <title>React App</title>
</head>
   <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>
         <script>
            window.onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {
               const token = '<access token>';
               const player = new Spotify.Player({
                  name: 'Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player',
                  getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(token); }
               });

               // Error handling
               player.addListener('initialization_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });
               player.addListener('authentication_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });

...
```

And I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) EMEError: No supported keysystem was found.     index.js:18
```

followed by a

```
Failed to initialize player
```

Comment: You probably want your API token removed from the question (maybe also contact a moderator or Stack Exchange support to have it removed from the edit history). Also, make sure to invalidate this one and get a new one for your app - the internet won't forget...

Comment: does this apply to all tokens or certain tokens?  Because this token is just a temporary access token and it's already expired

Comment: If it's expired, it's most likely fine. (However, passers-by like me won't know this and malicious actors could try it out whatsoever...) But better not include any tokens whatsoever. They may include information associated to your account, may be used to get your account blocked (even when expired, given that the system on the other end is overly cautious), etc. But making double sure not to include any prevents you from accidentally posting live tokens most of the time.

Comment: very true, thank you for covering :)

Answer (score 1):

We are experiencing the same issue with mobile Chrome browser versions 91.xxx, Beta and Canary 93.  It is the encryption for spotify which seems to have stopped working.  possibly will take a while for them to fix, if they fix it at all.

On desktop versions of all the above browsers, we are not having any issues yet.  Ironically, Spotify webplayer still works in all versions, including mobile chrome stable and canary.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue. What I have analyzed so far is that this **Spotify-SDK** is working perfectly when the chrome version is below `90.xxx` i.e. `89.xxx`. Can you please assist me in this matter? or how can I resolve this issue on the latest versions of chrome?

Comment: ive resorted to just using chrome beta 92 for my spotify project